# Keeping an NSOperation in a queue even after it completes

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsoperation

Typically once the `main` method of the an `NSOperation` is completed, the op is marked completed and it is removed from the queue. However, my op makes networking calls, and I want to handle retries. How do I keep an `NSOperation` in an `NSOperationQueue` until I explicitly say it's ok to remove it?

Comment: If you subclass the NSOperation you can explicitly tell it when it is complete. Keep a count of tries in the NSOperation subclass and only tell it that it is complete when it is successful or it gets to the predetermined number of tries.

Comment: Could you simply resubmit another NSOperation to the queue for retry?

Comment: @Fogmeister wait so if I subclass NSOperation, it doesn't "complete" until I say it's complete? It has nothing to do with the `main` method?

Comment: An NSOperation subclass is simply a state machine. If you don't set it to complete (I can't remember the exact property) then it won't finish. I would set up a loop inside the operation to just keep trying a specified number of times. If it is successful then set complete. If it fails just allow the loop to continue. If it gets to the number of tries then drop the loop and set complete.

Comment: @Fogmeister code-completion doesn't pull up anything similar to setFinished when I type in setX..do I have to manually synthesize that property or something?

Comment: one sec, will take a look at my current project. The properties are finished, executing and completed. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find the original source for the work I did on my current project.

I have subclassed NSOperation and do this...

Add private properties in the .m...

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL executing;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL finished;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL completed;
```

Init the operation...

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _executing = NO;
        _finished = NO;
        _completed = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Add the functions to return the properties...

```
- (BOOL)isExecuting { return self.executing; }
- (BOOL)isFinished { return self.finished; }
- (BOOL)isCompleted { return self.completed; }
- (BOOL)isConcurrent { return YES; }
```

In the "start" function (this is the bit that the operationQueue calls...

```
- (void)start
{
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        self.finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }

    // If the operation is not canceled, begin executing the task.
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    self.executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

Then in the main put your working code...

```
- (void)main
{
    @try {
        //this is where your loop would go with your counter and stuff
        //when you want the operationQueue to be notified that the work
        //is done just call...
        [self completeOperation];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception! %@", exception);
        [self completeOperation];
    }
}
```

Write the code for completeOperation...

```
- (void)completeOperation {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished = YES;

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}
```

That's it.

As long as you have these then the operation will work.

You can add as many other functions and properties as you wish.

In fact, I have actually subclassed this class as I have a function that does all the work for different types of object (it's an upload thing).  I have defined a function...

```
- (void)uploadData
{
    //subclass this method.
}
```

Then all I have in the subclasses is a custom "uploadData" method.

I find this really useful as it gives you fine grain control on when to finish the operation etc...

Comment: Thanks for the code samples. This is really helpful. Two questions: is it necessary to call the willChange/didChange value methods? Doesn't calling self.executing handle that automatically? And why do you use exception handlers in the main method? Is this a habit of yours or is this a recommended practice, and if so, why?

Comment: Yes it is necessary. The queue has an observer for the property "isExecuting" which is not the same as my "executing". By doing that it forces the queue to run - (BOOL)isExecuting. This is the first time I have used this. I read about this elsewhere and it has massively improved my codebase. It will be my MO from now on though. I thin kit was possibly a response to another SO question or something, can't find it.

Comment: The exception handlers are my own inclusion because my operations are all doing stuff over the network. It stops the whole thing failing (or the app crashing) when I don't have a connection. You prob won't need them.

Comment: I've found it! It was an answer to my own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278717/async-data-connections-ios